# Angular async pipe with as and let

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I have a store state that I'm getting using an observable and the `async` pipe. I'm using the `as` syntax to read the returned object.
This object is complex, and has fields that are referenced by another `async` observable to display information.
Could I do something like the following?

```
<div *ngIf="(fileObs$ | async) as files; let fileList= files[user.UserId]">
<div *ngFor="let file of fileList">
  ...
</div>
<!-- instead of -->
<div *ngFor="let file of files[user.UserId]">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ng-template` to declare new variable `fileList` and use `ng-container` to wait for asynchronous data to load which then activates the `template`

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="files; context:{file :fileObs$ | async}"></ng-container>

<ng-template #files let-fileList="file[user.UserId]">

   File List 
   <br>-------
   <div *ngFor="let file of fileList ">
      {{file}}
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngtemplate-amit?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I am not filtering `user.UserId` in my demo, but you can definitely do that while assigning data to `fileList` as `let-fileList="file[user.UserId]"`

Comment: This is nice, but I noticed that your fileObs$ method gets hit dozen of times. So, this wouldn't work well with a API fetch, which is sad.

Comment: If this is fetched from an API, you should use the `shareReplay` operator